.NET 4.7.2 app.config merging with secret.json
Ok, so I have an old .NET 4.7.2 Windows service with an app.config (xml format). And fyi I am using Autofac.
Now I want to extract some sensitive stuff from a secret.json (json format) that I will pull from Azure Keyvault in my pipeline.
In .NET Core, using appsettings.json, I would simply do:
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, true)
    .AddJsonFile("secrets.json", optional: true, true)
    .Build();

Which works perfectly and merges my multiple values from secrets.json in the appsettings file.
However, I don't know how to do the corresponding in .NET 4.7.2, especially since the files are of different format.
My program.cs looks like this:
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacConfig());

var container = builder.Build();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(container);

How do I make use of secrets.json and will it accept the mish mash of XML and JSON?
Thanks!

You can't use them and they can't be merged. .NET Framework's configuration system is inflexible. You can't even define a custom XML region without creating an assembly that defines it and reference it in app.config. On the other hand there's nothing special about appsettings.json  or secrets.json, they're files used by the JSON settings provider and Secrets provider. The .NET Core configuration middleware supports multiple providers and in fact, the default host also registers the Environment variable and CLI providers

On the other hand you can use most the Microsoft.Extensions.* libraries in .NET Framework as well. They target .NET Standard 2.0 so they can be used in all supported .NET Framework versions, ie 4.6.2 and later

Another option is to only use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration in your code and inject the settings into AutoFac either as key/value pairs or your own configuration objects. app.config settings will have to be loaded into AutoFac as well, and the rest of the application should only use the injected settings instead of going through Settings. That's a good design in general, which will allow you to load configuration from any source you want, not just app.config.

Another option is to use Microsoft.Extensions.Host and replace the DI middleware with AutoFac by using the Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection package. As the AutoFac integration docs show this can be as simple as Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
